# Getting data object within object in laravel mongodb?

Tags: php, laravel, mongodb

I am using laravel with MongoDB, My table structure is,

```
  "contractor_types" : [ 
            [ 
                [ 
                    "Priya2", 
                    "cont_0042"
                ]
            ], 
            2, 
            "4666", 
            "04/26/2017", 
            "04/28/2017", 
            [ 
                [ 
                    "nirmal2", 
                    "cont_0012"
                ]
            ], 
            1, 
            "1243", 
            "04/26/2017", 
            "04/26/2017"
        ],
    "created_at" : ISODate("2017-04-26T07:29:55.000Z"),
    "defect_id" : "1"
```

i want get the values "Priya2","cont_0042", how can i achieve this, please suggest any solution?

Comment: Some strange data structure you have there

Answer (score 0):

This is not "the" best solution but will be able to get the expected values

```
$a = '{
"contractor_types" : [ 
            [ 
                [ 
                    "Priya2", 
                    "cont_0042"
                ]
            ], 
            2, 
            "4666", 
            "04/26/2017", 
            "04/28/2017", 
            [ 
                [ 
                    "nirmal2", 
                    "cont_0012"
                ]
            ], 
            1, 
            "1243", 
            "04/26/2017", 
            "04/26/2017"
        ],
    "created_at" : "2017-04-26T07:29:55.000Z",
    "defect_id" : "1"
}';

$a = json_decode($a);

foreach ($a as $key => $value) {
    if (is_array($value)) {
        foreach ($value as $inner_arr) {
            if (is_array($inner_arr)) {
                foreach ($inner_arr as $innermost_arr) {
                    if (is_array($innermost_arr)) {
                        foreach ($innermost_arr as $expected_value) {
                            echo "$expected_value <br/>";
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Another alternative would be to use [array_walk_recursive](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk-recursive.php)